# Laravel 5 Include blade templates dynamically (replace div)

Tags: php, dom, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a CMS where users can create and edit their own content in their websites. I also provide the possibility to include forms and galleries by simply replacing specific Div's in their content.

In the past I simply exploded the content on these Div's to an array, replaced the whole Div's with the needed html code (by using PHP's include) to show the form or gallery at that exact position, imploded the whole array to a string again (html) and used in the website.

**Now I am trying to achieve the same in Laravel 5:**

```
// example plugins div in HTML
// ******************************
<div class="plugin form"></div>

// PageController.php
// ******************************
$page = Page::where(('url', '=', "home")->first();
$page->text = Helpers::getPlugins($page->text);


// Helpers.php (a non default custom class with functions)
// ******************************
public static function getPlugins($page)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($page, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
    $x = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");
    foreach ($x as $node)
    {
        if (strstr($node->getAttribute('class'), "plugin"))
        {
            $plugin = explode(" ",$node->getAttribute('class'));
            $filename = base_path() . "/resources/views/plugins/" . trim($plugin[1]) . ".blade.php";
            if (is_file($filename))
            {
                ob_start();
                include($filename);
                ob_get_contents();
                $node->nodeValue = ob_get_clean();
            }
            else
            {
                $node->nodeValue = "Plugin <strong>".$node->getAttribute('class')."</strong> Not found</div>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Sofar so good, the content is returned but what I get is all the pure text blade markup instead of the Laravel generated html which I want to use.

I think there is a way this could work but I cannot come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually building the template by using the method `BladeCompiler->compile()`, [read more here](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_compile)

Edit: I think the facade `Blade::compile()` will give you access to this function too, just add `use Blade` at the top of the file.

Comment: Tried it with Blade::compile($filename) and with Blade::compileString(ob_get_contents()), in both cases no result. dd(Blade::compile($filename)) returns null, dd(Blade::compileString($plugin)) ($plugin = ob_get_clean()) gives me the whole markup including php tags